# How do I perform t-test on the sample means from bootstrapping?

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

I'm doing data analysis on a voting activity with 6 voting options. Two groups of participants (experimental and control) participated in this voting activity. Then I'm comparing the relative frequency of each voting between those two groups and see if there's any difference between them. As those two groups have unequal sample size, I can't make a comparison directly with those two numbers. Therefore, I decided to do a bootstrapping for 1000 times and then do an independent sample t-test.

For example, for voting option A, 23.21% of control group participants and 19.8% of experimental group participants voted for it. After I sampled with replacement for 1000 times for the entire voting activity, I have 1000 relative frequency for A(experimental group) and another 1000 relative frequency for A(control group). Then I performed an independent sample t-test on those data.

**however, the problem is that, when I do t-test on those data received from bootstrapping, the t-test treats them as 1000+1000=2000 samples, therefore the p-value is significantly small (p=5.6232E-60) and degree of freedom is very large**

so my question is how do I do t-test in this situation after bootstrapping?
and if you don't think this is a good way to make comparison between two relative frequency, do you have any suggestions on how I should approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do what you're doing. What are you actually trying to achieve? [If you just want a comparison of means that doesn't rely on the particular distributional assumption, why not use the bootstrap samples to construct a CI for the difference in means?]

Comment: Hi @Glen_b I'm trying to compare between the voting results of each group. however, as those two groups have unequal sample size, I can't directly compare the percentage of people who voted for each option..thus I tried to form two "groups" of data by bootstrapping and then use independent samples t-test to compare the group means and see if there's any difference...

Comment: "*as those two groups have unequal sample size, I can't directly compare the percentage of people who voted for each option*" ... this seems to be a standard problem -- so why not? and as for what you  tried to do, that's not how the bootstrap works. It sounds like you should post a new question, asking about how to deal with your original problem rather than asking how to fix your mistaken solution to it.